# How to get a Row object back from SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been struggling for over an hour to do a seemingly quite simple thing in SQLAlchemy ORM. In the docs (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) there is a Row object which has properties such as _mapping and methods such as _todict() that I want to use. However, I CANNOT figure out how to get this Row object. When querying in a variety of ways:

```py
container = db_session.execute(select(Container).where(Container.process_id == process_id)).first()[0]
#or
container = db_session.scalar(select(Container).where(Container.process_id == process_id))
```

I always end up with an object like this: `<src.models.Container object at 0x1147e8760>` which gives the error `*** AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute '_mapping'` (since there is no such attribute on there). How can I get the `Row` object? The container inherits from the SQLAlchemy ORM class `DeclarativeBase`. My ultimate goal is to have a dictionary with the fields.

Comment: Querying ORM models returns models instances rather than rows.  Querying the underlying table should get you the rows, something like `db.execute(select(Container.__table__))`